# Simple program to remove punctuation

Tags: java

I am having a small issue with this tiny program. It is supposed to use a StringBuilder instance to remove punctuation. I didn't include all punctuation but for some reason when I compile this it does not remove the exclamation mark but it does the others. Quite odd. Here is my code:

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class Chapter1Reinforcement8 {

public static StringBuilder removePunctuation(StringBuilder s) {
    for (int i=0; i<=s.length(); i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i)=='!' | s.charAt(i)=='\'' | s.charAt(i)=='.'| s.charAt(i)==','| s.charAt(i)=='?') {
        s.deleteCharAt(i); 
    }
}
return s;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("Let's get Mike, Theresa, and Sam.!?");
    System.out.println("The old sentence is: " +s);
    StringBuilder newSentence = new StringBuilder();
    newSentence = removePunctuation(s);
    System.out.println("The new sentence is: " +newSentence);

}
}
```

Can anyone see the issue here?
Thank you!

Comment: I'd just use `String.replaceAll("[!'.,]", "")`.

Comment: In addition to Juned's answer, [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) is a list of operators in Java. You're using bitwise OR, when you should be using logical OR.

Comment: Two other issues: 1) You need to iterate the StringBuilder in reverse, otherwise you will skip over consecutive punctuation; 2) The for loop condition should be <, not <=.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over the `StringBuilder` backwards:

```
public static StringBuilder removePunctuation(StringBuilder s) {
    for (int i=s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(s.charAt(i)=='!' || s.charAt(i)=='\'' || s.charAt(i)=='.'| s.charAt(i)==','|| s.charAt(i)=='?') {
        s.deleteCharAt(i); 
    }
}
```

If you iterate forwards, when you delete the first punctuation mark from position `i`, the character that was at `i + 1` becomes the new character at `i`; you then increment `i`. If the new character at `i` was punctuation, you don't check it again.

Comment: Thank you that makes total sense!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `||` for OR comparison instead of logical OR `|` in your if condition. Change this :

```
    if(s.charAt(i)=='!' | s.charAt(i)=='\'' | s.charAt(i)=='.'| s.charAt(i)==','| s.charAt(i)=='?') {
```

to

```
    if(s.charAt(i)=='!' || s.charAt(i)=='\'' || s.charAt(i)=='.'|| s.charAt(i)==','|| s.charAt(i)=='?') {
```

Comment: If you say "should use" instead of "need to use," you would be correct, but that does not answer the question.  Using the short-circuit operator won't change the outcome.